# Remove singleton from Interval

Tags: intervals

I am using operations over `Interval` and the result of an intersection (or union) contains some singletons. Would it be possible to remove them ?

Example:

```
Interval[
  {2894486400, 2894486400},
  {2894659200, 2894832000},
  {2895004800, 2895004800},
  {2895177600, 2895350400}
]
```

Transformed in :

```
Interval[{2894659200, 2894832000}, {2895177600, 2895350400}]
```

Comment: Try `DeleteCases`: `DeleteCases[%, {$x_, $x_}]`

Comment: Works well !
Is the variable `$x_` a pattern ? I should learn that type of syntax :)

Comment: Not necessarily. When matching patterns I just specified a variable `x` so that the first and last elements in the lists had to be the same. I usually add a `$` so I don't get confused if another `x` has already been defined in my current context.

Comment: Thank you for the precision. I have not seen this very often, do you have any reference (book, article, etc.) that explains this ?

Comment: Nope. Just a personal preference. I do the same thing for functions like `FindRoot`: `$x /. FindRoot[Exp[$x]==5, {$x,1}]`. Like I said, complete personal preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For version 10 you might use:

```
interval ~Select~ DuplicateFreeQ
```

> ```
> Interval[{2894659200, 2894832000}, {2895177600, 2895350400}]
> ```

For other versions alternatives to `DeleteCases` include:

```
Select[interval, UnsameQ @@ # &]

Pick[#, UnsameQ @@@ #] & @ interval
```

---

#### Benchmarks

As requested:

```
generate[n_] := 
  Sort @ RandomInteger[n, ⌊.7n⌋] ~Partition~ 2 // Apply[Interval];

f1 = DeleteCases[{x_, x_}];
f2 = Select[DuplicateFreeQ];
f3 = Select[UnsameQ @@ # &];
f4 = Pick[#, UnsameQ @@@ #] &;
f5 = # /. {x_, x_} :> Sequence[] &;

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}, generate, 2^Range[7, 16], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

The lines are hard to see here but:

- `f1` and `f4` are the winners with nearly identical timings
- `f3` and `f5` are the slowest
- `f2` is in the middle
- All methods have the same complexity, unsurprisingly

If speed is the goal `f5` can be improved by using `Replace`:

```
f6 = Replace[#, {x_, x_} :> Sequence[], {1}] &; 

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f5, f6}, generate, 2^Range[7, 16], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

This shows that `DeleteCases` has only the slightest performance margin over `{x_, x_} :> Sequence[]` when the latter is used with a targeted *levelspec*, which I find somewhat surprising as I assumed the latter would incur additional evaluation.

Comment: Any advantage (speed, etc) of using one versus the others? I'm too lazy to test them lol.

Comment: @seismatica Let's find out. :-)

Comment: Very nice! +1..

Comment: Could you add `# /. {x_, x_} :> Sequence[] &`? It's bound to be slower, but I'm curious :).

Comment: @TeakeNutma Done.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but can you also try with `Rule` instead of `RuleDelayed`? The former is bound to be faster ...

Comment: @TeakeNutma Actually it makes no difference in this case; both `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` hold `Sequence[]` due to `SequenceHold` and they behave identically here.

Comment: Ah yes, that's very true. Thanks for the analysis; I'm just as surprised that `Replace` is on par with `DeleteCases`. Splicing out `Sequence`s must be very efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. In fact, there are multiple ways to do this. The most straightforward is to use [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html), as [@kale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1560/kale) points out in the comments:

```
interval = Interval[
 {2894486400, 2894486400}, 
 {2894659200, 2894832000}, 
 {2895004800, 2895004800}, 
 {2895177600, 2895350400}
];

DeleteCases[interval, {x_, x_}]
```

> ```
> Interval[{2894659200, 2894832000}, {2895177600, 2895350400}]
> ```

Here `x_` is a named [pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html). Because it occurs as `{x_, x_}`, it only matches those intervals that are singletons.

Another method, my favorite (but probably not as efficient as `DeleteCases`), is to replace the singletons with [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html), which get automatically spliced out:

```
interval /. {x_, x_} -> Sequence[]
```

> ```
> Interval[{2894659200, 2894832000}, {2895177600, 2895350400}]
> ```